# cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute a raw sql query through sqlalchemy in flask.
The raw sql query when run in `psql` gives out a proper output.

```
    postgres=# SELECT  distinct(user_id) FROM user_event_details WHERE  age >=19 AND granular_timestamp >=1493596800 AND granular_timestamp <=1517356800 AND event_name ='IB_TRANS' GROUP BY user_id;

    user_id 
  ---------
       6206
       5468
       5544
       4349
   (4 rows)
```

But when executed from sqlalchemy says `no such table:'user_event_details'`

the sqlalchemy code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

#from config import postgresURI
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from v3.setup.config import config

# flask application initializing
application = Flask(__name__)

# Cross origin resource sharing instantiation
CORS(application)

# wrapping around rest-plus api
application2 = Api(application, prefix="/api/v1", version='1.0', title='Rest-API', default='Version 1', default_label='API')

# SQLAlchemy binding
postgresURI = config['db']['db_url']
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
                                        'bind_db': postgresURI
                                        }
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
application.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

# SQLAlchemy instantiation
db = SQLAlchemy(application)
db.create_all(bind=['bind_db'])
db.create_all()
```

And then in one of routes file i have:

```
raw_sql = text(SELECT  distinct(user_id) FROM user_event_details WHERE  age >=19 AND granular_timestamp >=1493596800 AND granular_timestamp <=1517356800 AND event_name ='IB_TRANS' GROUP BY user_id;)
filtered_users = db.engine.execute(raw_sql)
```

and it gives out the error as:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user_event_details [SQL: "SELECT  distinct(user_id) FROM user_event_details WHERE age >=19 AND granular_timestamp >=1493596800 AND granular_timestamp <=1517356800 AND event_name ='IB_TRANS'  GROUP BY user_id,event_id;'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: You don't seem to be running against the same database. In `psql` you're talking to a Postgres server. In Alchemy, you're talking to a sqlite3 database.

Comment: @abarnert idk why its showing the sqlite3.OperationalError even I'm wondering but then i also have only 1 database and that is in postgres. Is it because of the `db.engine.execute` if so, what shoudl be the right approach?

Comment: How are you selecting an engine and connecting it? That's probably where the problem is, and you haven't shown us that code.

Comment: @abarnert my bad. have edited them now.

Comment: Any chance you have anything weird in the config file (or env variables) left over from prototyping against sqlite or something?

Comment: @abarnert no I cross-checked that already and besides the other endpoints are working fine which are also fetching same values from the config file. The only thing different in this endpoint is that here I'm not creating any orm object for querying but trying to execute a raw sql directly through the engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Flask-SQLAlchemy, the default engine is configured by [`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/config/#configuration-keys). You can then configure *additional* engines with `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`, but your default engine is the one in `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`.

Presumably, in your working ORM code, you're using the bind. (You haven't shown the working code, probably because it's working…) So it talks to Postgres.

But you're not passing a bind in your raw-SQL `db.engine` code, so it uses the default database. And you haven't configured the default database URI. The documentation doesn't explain what it defaults to if you don't set anything, but from the error message, it's clearly a `sqlite3` database. Which obviously won't have your schema, or anything else useful in it.

From [a github issue for Flask-Migrate](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/58), it looks like the default is `sqlite3://`, which opens a `sqlite3` non-persistent `:memory:` database, and there's no warning for doing this (possibly because it's handy for initial exploratory development?).

See [Multiple Databases with Binds](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/binds/) for more details.

Anyway, you *could* change your raw-SQL code to also use the bind, but really, the best solution is probably to just add this:

```
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgresURI
```

… and maybe even consider getting rid of the bind, since you don't have any need for multiple databases connections, and they're only leading to confusion.